# TRIAC Voltage Control

Tags: power, capacitor, resistance, triac, diac

I have the simple Triac voltage control circuit.

[image]

The values of resistance and capacitor are 10 kohm and 0.1 uF respectively.

I want to know that the following:

1. How can we calculate these values of resistance (10 kohm) and capacitor (0.1 uF)?
2. What will be the value of current through DIAC?

Comment: If the DIAC has a threshold of 30V and is 500 ohms then 60mA max but limited by source impedance. So a better design uses 2 caps to get more phase shift and 470k below the pot with another 100nF above the pot. https://tinyurl.com/yg3d7tvp

Answer (score 2):

Your schematic is wrong (missing a wire).

The wiper on the pot should be connected to the "bottom" end of the element. Otherwise there is no way for the diac to conduct sufficient current to trigger the triac.

The calculation of the capacitor and pot values is a bit tricky, but there are really only four situations you need to worry about- 50Hz and 60Hz and 120VAC and 240VAC (save for Japan with 100/200VAC).

Here are the well-established standard values from the GE SCR Manual 1972:

[image]

The timing is different if the triac has previously triggered, leading to the annoying "snap-on" effect where the same pot position at lower power settings can have a corresponding phase control output that is either zero or somewhat on, depending on the history, a kind of hysteresis.

The diac average current is low- it conducts brief sharp spikes of current to trigger the triac gate. The peak current is poorly defined since it depends on the capacitor, triac gate and diac characteristics, but might be as much as several hundred mA peak.